# Upgrading to rails 3.1 breaks production mode when using passenger & cache_classes = true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Folks,

i have serious issues when trying to migrate my application from rails 3 to rails 3.1. i followed the guides, moved my assets, updated gems and reconfigured my configs.

The first thing I stumbled over was that

> no such file or directory app/config/environment

error, that various people reported. Sadly, the common solution to just alter the ownership of environment.rb to somebody else than root doesnt seem to apply in my case.

By grepping through my apps directories I found where the error message actually came from, namely app/test/test_helper.rb which I moved from the rails 3 directory has the following wrongly automatically generated line:

> require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', **FILE**)

which I changed to

> require File.expand_path('../../../config/environment', **FILE**)

so the error message vanished. That made me already become nervous, because why the hell is the test_helper.rb file interpreted at all when trying to firing it up in production mode? I needed no testing for now, so I simply moved (i.e. renamed) the whole app/test directory. Good for now? No, not at all, the new error message coming up is

> Abort testing: Your Rails environment is running in production mode!

WTF? RailsEnv in passenger (3.0.9) for sure is production. When I change config.cache_classes to false everything works perfectly!

I have no clue where to search anymore, that error message I pasted above doesnt seem to have been discussed at all yet.

Any hints?

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I'm having a similar issue. setting config.cache_classes = false makes everything work as expected...